# flutter: how to add a scroll bar in the right of the ListView?

Tags: flutter

I'm working with flutter. I want to add a scroll bar to the right of the `ListView` just similar to the net page scroll bar, but I haven't found any related property. Is this possible? The basic code is ready for your advice.

```
ListView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     children: <Widget>[
        // I will put some HTML code here,
     ],
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are packages available if you want custom scrollbar or you can use flutter inbuilt scrollbar widget too
[draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar)

I think better to use `CupertinoScrollbar` instead of Scrollbar. `CupertinoScrollbar` is can touch and scroll to the bottom

**Ex:**

```
CupertinoScrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Item: ${index + 1}"),
                  ));
                }),
          ),
```

**Or** You can use `Scrollbar`

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

Scrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Item: ${index + 1}"),
                  ));
                }),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks, CupertinoScrollbar is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `Listview` with the `ScrollBar` widget.

```
  
ScrollBar(
 isAlwaysShown: true, // optionel
 child: ListView(
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       children: <Widget>[
        // I will put some HTML code here,
       ],
    ),
 ),
```